# Error while fill order with 0x Protocol using BUSD

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, web3js, binance-smart-chain

I'm working with [0x Protocol](https://github.com/0xProject/protocol), and and want to support users use BUSD to fill order to purchase NFT item.
Basically, I do flowing steps:

```
const ethTokenAddress = contractWrappers.contractAddresses.etherToken;      // Contract BUSD
const ethToken = new ERC20TokenContract(ethTokenAddress, Web3.givenProvider);

const zrxTokenAddress = contractWrappers.contractAddresses.zrxToken;
const zrxToken = new ERC20TokenContract(zrxTokenAddress, Web3.givenProvider);

// 1. Allow the 0x ERC20 Proxy to move ZRX on behalf of takerAccount
const takerZRXApprovalTxHash = await zrxToken
                            .approve(contractWrappers.contractAddresses.erc20Proxy, UNLIMITED_ALLOWANCE_IN_BASE_UNITS)
                            .sendTransactionAsync({ from: taker });

// 2. Allow the 0x ERC20 Proxy move BUSD on behalf of takerAccount
const takerErc20ProxyApprovalTxHash = await ethToken
                                .approve(contractWrappers.contractAddresses.erc20Proxy, UNLIMITED_ALLOWANCE_IN_BASE_UNITS)
                                .sendTransactionAsync({ from: taker });

// 3. Fill Order
const txHash = await contractWrappers.exchange
                        .fillOrder(sraOrder, takerAssetAmount, sraOrder.signature)
                        .sendTransactionAsync({
                            from: taker,
                            ...TX_DEFAULTS,
                            value: calculateProtocolFee([sraOrder]),
                        });
```

But I encounter error with FillOrder function, there for transaction is failed.
Please help me resolve this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the `fillOrder` function source code, including its dependencies (e.g. other functions that it calls and property definitions)?

Comment: @PetrHejda, you can check it out here : https://github.com/0xProject/0x-protocol-specification/blob/master/v3/v3-specification.md#creating-an-order

Comment: That's just the function header. Do you have the source code of its body?